# Как выполнять jQuery-код только на определенной странице?

Tags: jquery

Есть JS-файл, общий для всех страниц.
Есть jQuery-код, который работает с элементами определенной страницы.
На страницах, на которых нет нужных элементов, возникает ошибка.
Как выполнять jQuery-код только на определенной странице, не вынося его в отдельный файл?

Comment: `if(el.length){
... Выполнить ....
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, можно проверять адрес и прекращать выполнение, если подстрока в адресе не найдена (если что, обернув код в `(function(){ … })()`, чтобы можно было воспользоваться `return`):

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('…') === -1) return;
```

Но лучше, конечно, просто проверять, есть ли нужные элементы на текущей странице. Например, так:

```
if ($('.element').length === 0) return;
```

Comment: Почему-то проверять наличие элементов я не догадался :-)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сверять `location.pathname` или `location.href`:

```html
 //значения location.pathname, при которых будет запускаться ваш скрипт
var pagesWithScript = ["/page1", "/page2"];

if (pagesWithScript.indexOf(location.pathname) != -1 ) {
  //ваш скрипт
}
```

`location.pathname` — относительный путь до страницы. К примеру, для `https://example.com/page` location.pathname = `"/page"`